# Need to be able to check column by one by one and for a certain string but can't figure out a way to do so

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2014

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ7Oe.png)Is there a way for me to have a String and check within multiple columns in another table in order starting from 1 until I get a match?

I have table with a few fields

```
 Medicine   
-----------
 Advil 
 Tylenol
 Midol
```

I need to check it against another table and check column in order for the medicine above.

```
MedsToTry1  | MedsToTry2 | MedsToTry3 | MedsToTry4 | MedsToTry5 | MedsToTry6 |
------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
 NotAdvil      Advil        Null         Null         Null         Null
 Tylenol       Ibuprofen    NotTylenol   Null         Null         Null
 NotMidol      NotAdvil     Ibuprofen    Midol        Null         Null
```

So I have to go through each one of the fields in the first table and search for them in the 'MedsToTry1' field if not there then on 'MedsToTry2' and so on until found.

I've tried concatentation on all the strings in the MedsToTry fields and searching for the string in there but it doesn't guarantee that it'll be in order and I need for 'MedsToTry1' to be checked first.

I tried to use COALESCE but it returns the fields on MedsToTry1 since they're all not null but won't go to MedsToTry2 to see if it's there.

Is there a way for me to do this? Have a String and check within multiple columns in another table in order starting from 1 until I get a match?

If I need to provide more information please let me know. I pretty new to SQL so I'm take any and all help I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there... I'm a little bit confused with your model, are "advil, tylenol, midol" fields or data? Are MedsToTry1 .. 6 different tables or one table and each 1..6 are columns? I'm assuming that for `Not"Medicine"` means that for that N option that medicine should not be used right? So regardless of your answer for this questions one thing for sure is that your model is designed wrong for this. I can help, but only when you give an explanation on those questions and what is the requirements. Right now your question is clearly a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your table is - quite probably - not the real source table. If you can query against this, it was much better. This is - again my guessing - the result of a *pivot* operation, where a *row-wise* table is transformed to a *side-by-side* or *column-wise* format.

You did not state the expected output. For the next time, or to improve this question, please look at my code and try to prepare a *stand-alone* example to reproduce your issue yourself. This time I've done it for you:

First we have to declare *mockup-tables* to simulate your issue:

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(Medicine VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES
 ('Advil')
,('Tylenol')
,('Midol');

DECLARE @tblB TABLE(RowId INT,MedsToTry1 VARCHAR(100),MedsToTry2 VARCHAR(100),MedsToTry3 VARCHAR(100),MedsToTry4 VARCHAR(100),MedsToTry5 VARCHAR(100),MedsToTry6 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES
 (1,'NotAdvil','Advil',Null,Null ,Null,Null)
,(2,'Tylenol','Ibuprofen','NotTylenol',Null ,Null,Null)
,(3,'NotMidol','NotAdvil','Ibuprofen','Midol',Null,Null);
```

--This is the query (use your own table names to test this in your environment)

```
SELECT B.RowId 
      ,C.*
FROM @tblB b
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,b.MedsToTry1)
                  ,(2,b.MedsToTry2) 
                  ,(3,b.MedsToTry3) 
                  ,(4,b.MedsToTry4) 
                  ,(5,b.MedsToTry5) 
                  ,(6,b.MedsToTry6)) C(MedRank,Medicin)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tblA A WHERE A.Medicine=C.Medicin);
```

The idea in short:

The trick with `CROSS APPLY (VALUES...` will return each *name-numbered* column (MedsToTry1, MedsToTry2...) in one row, together with a rank. This way we do not lose the information of the sort order or the position within the table.

The `WHERE` will reduce the set to rows, where there exists a corresponding medicine in the other table.

The result

```
RowId   MedRank Medicin
1       2       Advil
2       1       Tylenol
3       4       Midol
```